# Usage of json.dumps

Tags: json, python-2.7

I would like to use `json.dumps` to automatically output the value of the `hostname` field.

```
{
  "code": 200,
    "success": true,
      "data": [{
        "xxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "hostname": None,
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": "xxxx",
        "xxxx": [{
          "xxxx": "xxxx",
          "xxxx": "xxxx"
        }]
      }]
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

That's unclear question but i try to give you an answer. You can try this:

```
import json
import sys

data={"code": 200, "success": True, "data": [{"xxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "hostname": None, "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": [{"xxxx": "xxxx", "xxxx": "xxxx"}]}]}

json_str = json.dumps(data)
resp = json.loads(json_str)

print (resp)
print (resp['data'][0]['hostname'])
```

Than result will be:

```
{u'code': 200, u'data': [{u'xxx': u'xxxx', u'hostname': None, u'xxxx': [{u'xxxx': u'xxxx'}]}], u'success': True}
None
```